# How to enable Linux penguin logo on Android?

Tags: console, boot, framebuffer, graphical-logo, omap

TI OMAP 4460 + Android file system + Android Linux kernel 3.0

I have set CONFIG_LOGO, CONFIG_VT and CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE in kernel config, logo image type is CLUT224.

Then I saw strange things, almost 10 seconds later after kernel booting, a broken image appeared, looked like the head of the penguin, only several pixels of lines on the top of sreen. Then I reboot again and agian, sometimes I saw the 'ANDROID' characters, just below the penguin's head, but sometimes not.

see the link[enter link description here](http://e2e.ti.com/support/omap/f/849/t/313921.aspx)

My colleague reminded me I should disable the Android booting logo('ANDROID' characters, to be exactly), because it needs to open a tty console. That might have effect on something?

Besides, why the penguin logo showed up so late? I added some print in drivers/video/fbmem.c
fb_do_show_logo(), this function was called at 3 seconds after kernel booting. Why I saw the logo at 10 seconds?